# Images flicker when served by Rails to Chrome or Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, google-chrome, safari, flicker

In performing some cross-browser testing, I noticed that my images flicker when the page is refreshed - but just with Chrome/Safari - not with Firefox or IE. A white area is displayed, then the image is displayed.

I had some identical markup provided by the designer that didn't show this problem. Finally, I narrowed it down to Rails itself. When Rails serves the page, it flickers (in Chrome/Safari). When the same markup is just opened in the browser from the local file system, it doesn't flicker.

Eventually, I decided to see if other Rails sites had this problem - and they do! basecamphq.com flickers on refresh with Chrome, but doesn't (or at least, it does much less) with Firefox.

Is this a known problem with WebKit? Is there a solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: In production images should be served by whatever front-end server you are using, commonly Apache or Nginx. This issue is not related to Rails, as Rails nor the Rails server will server any images when in production.

Comment: I don't know that this has anything necessarily to do with the way images are served, but with how a page with such images is served by Rails is rendered by a particular browser. As I said, a (production) Rails site like like BaseCamp flickers with WebKit browsers, but doesn't with other browsers. Non-Rails sites don't flicker with either. That points to some kind of interaction between Rails and WebKit.

Comment: I think I have that too, in a Sinatra app running on Nginx... am I right that this doesn't seem to happen when the inspector is open? I thought it was LESS.js, but I replaced the .less with a compiled .css and it still happens.

Comment: I have that when RSpec is running tests

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that large images that are resized via the html width/height attribute tend to flicker in certain browsers. The solution - have the image resized via ImageMagick or similar before serving

Comment: This wouldn't be Rails-specific, which is the effect I'm seeing.

Comment: I wasn't setting the dimensions in HTML, but I was setting them in CSS. However, removing the dimensions didn't remove the flicker in those browsers.